# List of zipcodes - MySql JSON Array

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

So I have a list of zipcodes, how should I save it into mySql? I was thinking as a JSON Array. Now I'm stuck at finding a particular zipcode in the given JSON Array.

```
insert into Test values (2, '[22279, 22510, 12345, 65412, 78954]');
```

I thought I'd use the JSON_CONTAINS, but I can't seem to figure it out how to use it:

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE 
    JSON_CONTAINS(testJson, 22079);
```

I'm getting this error with the above query:

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE      JSON_CONTAINS(testJson, 22079) LIMIT 0, 1000  Error Code: 3146. Invalid data type for JSON data in argument 2 to function json_contains; a JSON string or JSON type is required.
```

Oh and how would I use hibernate to do the above like query?

Comment: what is your table structure ? what do you mean by list , is `List` interface used in java ? So your code to understand your problem

Comment: Its a simple test table with an ID column and a JSON column.

Comment: Why not normalise your schema

Comment: Okay, please do suggest a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working:

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE 
    JSON_CONTAINS(testJson, '12345');
```

This also worked from Postman:

```
{
    "test": {
        "id": "5",
        "testJson" : "[22079, 22310, 12345, 65412, 78954]"
    }
}
```

Java pojo looks like:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
@Entity
public class Test {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String testJson;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTestJson() {
        return testJson;
    }

    public void setTestJson(String testJson) {
        this.testJson = testJson;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that if the values in the list are strings, you have to search for them with double-quotes (because strings have to be surrounded by double-quotes to be valid JSON).

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  testJson JSON
);

insert into Test (id, testJson) values (1, '["Hello", "Goodbye", "Now", "Later", "Sometime"]');
insert into Test (id, testJson) values (2, '["Hi", "Bye", "Today", "Tomorrow", "Yesterday"]');

SELECT id FROM Test WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(testJson, '"Hi"');
```

returns: `2`